# Get address using geolocation in http website

Tags: azure, google-chrome, geolocation, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

Recently I created a website in asp.net core and hosted in Azure Shared tier (non-secure). there is one feature on my website, get user address based on geolocation and autofill registration form.

**Problem**

1. getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins (As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS.)
2. The site is very small and I don't want to spend money on SSL certificate. (I can go with free SSL https://letsencrypt.org/)
3. Custom SSL certificate hosting only available on Azure Basic and above tier.

Is there any solution/workaround available?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/) to get a certificate for free.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up CloudFlare Free Plan and use their free SSL.

https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/